# How to divide variable from input by two

Tags: python

On line 7 and 14 I cant figure out how to divide the variable.

```py
import keyboard
import random


def main(Number, Start):
    Number = random.randrange(1,100)
    Start = False
    QA = input('Press "K" key to begin')
    if keyboard.is_pressed('K'):
        Start = True
    input('I"m thinking of a random number and I want that number divisible by two')
    print(Number)
    input('Please divide this by two. *IF IT IS NOT POSSIBLE RESTART GAME*\n')
    if QA == int(Number) / 2:
        print('.')
    else:
        print('.')

main(Number=' ' ,Start=' ')
```

Comment: `QA` is a string and can't be compared to a number. Convert it to a number.

Comment: We cannot see line numbers here, but "line 7" seems to be a boolean, which cannot be divided. Otherwise, correct, `input()` is always a string, and will never equal a number

Comment: There's a lot of mess in this code

Comment: Sorry! I meant to clarify the number variable

Comment: You're missing `QA = int(input('I"m thinking of `, and you can remove `QA =` from the first input, and remove `keyboard.is_pressed` since that doesn't "wait" the way you want it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want:

- Pick a random number
- Make user divide this number by two (?)
- Do something based on whether the guess is correct

What is wrong with your code:

- You are not picking a number divisible by two. The easiest way to ensure that your number is, indeed, divisible by two, is by picking a random number and *then* multiplying it by two: `my_number = 2 * random.randrange(1, 50)`. Note the change in the range. Also note that the upper limit is not inclusive, which may be not what your meant here. A typical check for divisibility by N is using a modulo operator: `my_number % N == 0`. If you want users to actually handle odd numbers differently, you would need to write a separate branch for that.
- `input` returns a string. In your case, `QA = input('Press "K" key to begin')` returns `"K"` IF user has actually done that or random gibberish otherwise. Then you are checking a completely unrelated state by calling `keyboard.is_pressed`: what you are meant to do here is to check whether the user has entered `K` (`if QA == "K"`) or, if you just want to continue as soon as `K` is pressed, use `keyboard.wait('k')`. I would recommend sticking to `input` for now though. Note that lowercase/uppercase letters are not interchangeable in all cases and you probably do not want users to be forced into pressing `Shift+k` (as far as I can tell, not the case with the `keyboard` package).
- `input('I"m thinking of` does not return anything. You probably want `print` there, possibly with [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) to print that prompt along with your random number.
- `input('Please divide this by two.` does not return anything, either. And you definitely want to store that somewhere or at least immediately evaluate against your expected result.
- There is no logic to handle the results any differently.
- Your function does not really need any arguments as it is written. `Start` is not doing anything, either.
- Variable naming goes against most of the conventions I've seen. It is not a big problem *now*, but it will become one should you need help with longer and more complex code.

Amended version:

```
import random
import keyboard


def my_guessing_game():
    my_number = random.randrange(1, 50) * 2
    # game_started = False
    print('Press "K" to begin')
    keyboard.wait('k')
    # game_started = True
    print(f"I'm thinking of a number and I want you to divide that number by two. My number is {my_number}")
    user_guess = input('Please divide it by two: ')
    if int(user_guess) == my_number / 2:
        # handle a correct guess here
        print('Correct!')
        pass
    else:
        # handle an incorrect guess here
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the modulo operator % to test whether Number is divisible by 2:

if Number % 2 == 0:
print('.')
else:
print('.')

This will check whether the remainder of Number divided by 2 is equal to 0, which indicates that Number is divisible by 2.